# Cannot Import Assert in Java

Tags: java, junit

I'm working on creating my unit tests for a bookstore class I created, but when I try to import the following:

```
package BookStore;
import static ProvidedClasses.BookStoreFactory.getBookStoreInstance;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

I get the message: "package org.junit does not exist" for the last two lines.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Make sure that you have the junit jar file. You have to download it and add it to yout project or you can also use Maven [download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12)

Comment: If you are using the IDE, you missed adding JUnit library to your project.

Comment: Just a note: Packages are conventionally written in lowercase only. CamelCase is for classes.

Comment: Add your setup, can't answer with out more information.

Comment: Typically, this is a classpath issue - your build tool can't find `junit.jar` which contains the classes in `org.junit`. Often this is down to a problem between your IDE (intelliJ, Eclipse,...) and your build tool (Maven, Gradle, Ant,...).